# numbering column in access causing query to stop responding

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I ran some code to number old records in a column to order items in a datasheet subform however after updating the column in the inventory transactions table when opening the main form that relies on it. It runs a query to determine the customers balance due and the query for that is taking forever to run like 2-3 minutes or more however reverting to an old copy of the data it runs fine and all I did was renumber records in one column most of which had 1s in them the code to re-number the records:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Long
Dim OID As Long
Dim stringSQL as String
i = 1
stringSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Inventory Transactions] " _
          & "WHERE [OrderID] >  0 Order By [OrderID],[TransactionID]"
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(stringSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
With rst
OID = rst!OrderID
    Do Until .EOF
        If OID = rst!OrderID Then
        .Edit
            !OrderLineNumber = i
        .Update
        .MoveNext
        i = i + 1
        Else
        OID = rst!OrderID
        i = 1
        End If
    Loop
    .Close
End With
Set rst = Nothing
```

Edit 1:

I continued playing with this today and the query that is breaking the 2nd level subquery that actually references the inventory transactions table that I changed runs fine but go up a level to subquery1 which references subquery2 and a sum of payments query and it chokes however sum of payments only refernces the payments table.

Edit 2:

I did some more testing today Subquery2 and sum of payments query both run faster than what I can time with a stopwatch but when combined they take approximately 1:45 there are only 5 columns in subquery1 four from subquery2 and 1 from the sum of payments 3 of the first 4 are sum and the last is group by and then the one from sum of payments is group by

### Subquery 2:

```
SELECT 
  CLng((nz([UnitsSold])*nz([UnitPrice]))*(1-nz([Discount]))*100)/100 AS [Line Total], 
  CLng([Line Total]*(1+nz([SalesTaxRate]))*100)/100 AS [Line Total With Tax], 
  [Line Total With Tax]-[Line Total] AS [Line Tax], 
  [Inventory Transactions].* 
  FROM [Inventory Transactions] 
  WHERE ((([Inventory Transactions].OrderID) Is Not Null));
```

### sum of payments Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Payments.OrderID, 
  Sum(Payments.PaymentAmount) AS [Total Payments]
FROM Payments 
GROUP BY Payments.OrderID;
```

### Subquery 1:

```
SELECT 
  [Balance Due By Customers Subquery2].OrderID, 
  Sum([Balance Due By Customers Subquery2].[Line Total]) AS [SumOfLine Total], 
  Sum([Balance Due By Customers Subquery2].[Line Tax]) AS [SumOfLine Tax], 
  Sum([Balance Due By Customers Subquery2].[Line Total With Tax]) AS [SumOfLine Total With Tax], 
  [Sum Of Payments Query].[Total Payments]
FROM [Balance Due By Customers Subquery2] 
  LEFT JOIN [Sum Of Payments Query] 
  ON [Balance Due By Customers Subquery2].OrderID = [Sum Of Payments Query].OrderID
GROUP BY [Balance Due By Customers Subquery2].OrderID, 
  [Sum Of Payments Query].[Total Payments];
```

Comment: Where's your query that takes forever to run?

Comment: its a very complex make table query that has like 4 subquerys only one of which references the inventory transactions table and i removed inventory transactions.* and added all the other columns but that one

Comment: do you have an index on the Orderlinenumber?

Comment: no should I have one?

Comment: ok tested it no joy might be a little bit faster but not much

Comment: Yeh, it's weird the query chokes, but runs fine using the old data.  The `OrderLineNumber` field isn't even used in these queries.

Comment: "Database Tools" includes a table analyzer.  Try running it on `Inventory Transactions` -- both versions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Embedded functions like `nz()` slow your query.  They also make your SQL illegible.  Improve your tables so `nz()` is not needed.  For example, open your table in design view and give each numeric field a default value of zero.
2. Test each query without the `DISTINCTROW` keyword.  The queries should run faster.  I expect it's doing nothing, because I notice each query has an `ID` record in the `SELECT` clause.  (Just see if the same number of records is returned -- yep, it's doing nothing.)
3. You seem to be grouping by `OrderID` on a query result that also groups by `OrderID`.  The higher-level `GROUP BY` is doing nothing.  Which means some of your `SUM()` functions are doing nothing...except being slow.
4. `Subquery 2` is a mess (sorry to be blunt).  Do you need all those fields?  If so, at least have mercy on us by shortening the syntax:  `[Inventory Transactions].PriceChanged` can be presented as `PriceChanged`.  And (at least in the future) avoid spaces in table and query names -- you will [save yourself trouble](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=2190).
5. Calculations like `[Line Total]` might work better in a preliminary query.  At least it would be cleaner programming, in my opinion.
6. Use a period at the end of each sentence.  It will help us understand your post.

Bad design is brittle:  it becomes broken for mysterious reasons.  Good design facilitates query functioning, and in this case you need it for trouble-shooting.  Fixing a query often requires

1. reduction and simplification, until the problem disappears
2. building back up to the needed result.  (More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/122139).)

Based on your *Edit 2*, you need to use this approach on `Subquery 2`.  **Start with the simplest possible query that combines the two others.**  Leave off the aggregate functions (`SUM()`, `GROUP BY`) -- somehow they are messing things up.

Before simplifying in a way that changes the data result, you can simplify these queries by merely improving syntax.  For example, here is `Subquery 1` with alias names for the nested queries -- much easier to read:

```
SELECT 
  BalanceDue.OrderID, 
  Sum(BalanceDue.[Line Total]) AS [SumOfLine Total], 
  Sum(BalanceDue.[Line Tax]) AS [SumOfLine Tax], 
  Sum(BalanceDue.[Line Total With Tax]) AS [SumOfLine Total With Tax], 
  SumPmts.[Total Payments]
FROM [Balance Due By Customers Subquery2] AS BalanceDue
  LEFT JOIN [Sum Of Payments Query] AS SumPmts
  ON BalanceDue.OrderID = SumPmts.OrderID
GROUP BY BalanceDue.OrderID, 
  SumPmts.[Total Payments];
```

Comment: added a cleaner version of subquery 2

Comment: oh and I didn't write the queries but they worked just fine before I updated the contents of the one column

Comment: Alright confirmed that the aggregate functions are causing the problem but I need to have them without them I have 98,996 records and with them only 22,625

Comment: Run Table Analyzer (Tools menu).  Experiment with the queries.  There's no "magic bullet" answer, no glaring defect -- someone would have pointed it out by now.